# ASP.NET 2.0 InterlockedIncrement Error

Tags: asp.net, entry-point

I am tasked with troubleshooting an ASP.NET 2.0 application that was moved from a 32-bit server to a 64-bit server.  The application wasn't written in Visual Studio but in something like FrontPages.  It worked on the old server but on the new server we get the following error:

"Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'

It sounded like it could be an issues with the 64 bit versus 32 bit but I haven't been able to find anything that actually points me to where I need to change some type of parameter I have not been able to solve the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your app have any DLLs in the `Bin` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the

<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Data.Odbc" %> to

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd78zt0c.aspx):

> **Platforms:**
>
> Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2
>   x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported),
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows
>   Server 2003 SP2

Do you meet the requirements?

Comment: The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.  We have two other ASP.NET webpages that are running without problems.  This is one an application and is the only one acting up.

Comment: Also, only Files Services role and Web Server (IIS) roles installed

Comment: There is a `InterlockedIncrement64` is your app compiled to target x64? Assuming your using .NET Interlocked.Increment.

Comment: I was told this was not compiled...it was created using frontpage.